# Rails 5: How do I loop over a hash with each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get a specific output from the Typeform API.

This is the response I get back.

Example response:

```
"answers": [
        {
          "field": {
            "id": "hVONkQcnSNRj",
            "type": "dropdown",
            "ref": "my_custom_dropdown_reference"
          },
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Job opportunities"
        },
        {
          "field": {
            "id": "RUqkXSeXBXSd",
            "type": "yes_no",
            "ref": "my_custom_yes_no_reference"
          },
          "type": "boolean",
          "boolean": false
        }
       ]
```

Why does `.first` work and why does `.second` not work ?

My `OrdersController.rb`

```
  items = response.parsed_response["items"]
  items.each do |item|
    @order = current_user.orders.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id"]) do |order|
      item["answers"].each do |answer|
      order.landing_id = item["landing_id"]
      order.email = item["hidden"]["email"]
      order.price = item["hidden"]["price"]
      order.moduls = item["hidden"]["moduls"]
      order.project = item["hidden"]["project"]
      order.website = answer.first # This works
      order.payment = answer.second # undefined method `second' for #<Hash:0x11f83e78>
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hashes are not ordered, they are accessed by keys.

Comment: Example response not associated with controller code, because in example "answers" value is Array, but in fact it is Hash - undefined method `second' for #< **Hash** :0x11f83e78>

Comment: @Iceman what would be the right way to access the hashes ?

Comment: `answer[:field][:id]` e.g.

Comment: I tried every possible outcome, but none of the suggestions worked.

Comment: @ArnasKlasauskas Which information in answer hash above you wanna add to `order.website` and `order.payment`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

`answers.each { |answer| answer[:field] }`

or, if you want ids for example

`answers.map { |answer| answer.dig(:field, :id) }`

Answer (score 0):

Because ruby hash doesn't have any second or last methods. You can access value with the help of keys. e.g. answer[:type], answer[:text]

Answer (score 0):

`item["answers"].each do |answer|` was an overkill. The solution was as simple as that:

`order.website = item["answers"][1]["text] # Access the first field of answers array`

`order.payment = item["answers"][2]["text] # Access the second field of answers array`